# Segue to another Storyboard with NavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to fix an onboarding/walkthrough to my app. Everything works as it should, except that when I navigate to the first page, navigationController disappears.
When I close the app and start it again, there is NavigationController/bar there.
is there something wrong in my code?

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyborad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainVC = storyborad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC") as! ViewController
    self.present(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to present your VC with a `UINavigationController`, or push a new VC onto the current `navigationController`.

First approach pushing mainVC to current `navigationController` (Probably will work better in your case):

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyborad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainVC = storyborad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC") as! ViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: true)
}
```

Second approach, presenting with initializing a navigationController:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyborad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainVC = storyborad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC") as! ViewController
    self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```